# How to implement a function template in PHP 5.2 like this in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, closures, php-5.3, php-5.2

This code runs very well in PHP 5.3 but not in PHP 5.2. How can you implement something like this in PHP 5.2?

```
echo "Calling func....<br/>";
function template_func( $data=array(), $func ) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $func( $v );    
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

$data = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );

template_func( $data, function ( $v ) { 
    echo "<li>$v</li>"; 
} );

template_func( $data, function ( $v ) { 
    echo "<li><span class='style'>$v</span></li>"; 
} );
```

Comment: You could use `create_function` in older versions of PHP, but it'd probably be better to use callbacks.

Comment: You can use sprintf and provide the pattern string as parameter. Your PHP 5.3 code would benefit from that as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) / [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). You will have to pass the function name as a string. You can also call methods and static methods this way, [please check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#example-4702).

You could also use [`is_callable()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) to verify whether the parameter can be called as a function.

A simple example with `call_user_func()`:

```
function template_func( $data=array(), $func ) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        call_user_func($func, $v);    
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

function spannedList ( $v ) { 
    echo "<li><span class='style'>$v</span></li>"; 
}
template_func($data, 'spannedList');
```

**An alternative method** would be to use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). This way, you don't even have to change the definition of your `template_func()`.

Comment: how is your `call_user_func($func, $v)` any different than just `$func($v)`?

Comment: @newacct If you do not use `create_function()`, you can use `call_user_func()` and pass the function name as a parameter. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I believe that `$func($v)` already works with a function name `$func` (`create_function()` simply returns a function name also), so there is no need to use `call_user_func()`

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the anonymous functions to `create_function`:

```
template_func( $data, create_function( '$v', '
    echo "<li>$v</li>"; 
' ) );

template_func( $data, create_function( '$v', '
    echo "<li><span class=\'style\'>$v</span></li>"; 
' ) );
```